# Why was Messi not on the UEFA shortlist for 2018 Player of the Year?

Tags: football, uefa

This is Lionel Messi's 2017/18 season:

- La Liga
- Copa del Rey
- Spanish Super Cup
- Onze D'or
- Most goals
- Most assists
- Most key passes
- Most chances created
- Most dribbles
- Most MOTMs in Europe's TOP 5 leagues
- Most freekicks
- 5th Golden Shoe

Why wasn't he on the UEFA shortlist for Player of the Year?

Comment: Related article on the UEFA website: [Modrić, Ronaldo and Salah up for Player of the Year](https://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/news/newsid=2565827.html). Messi ended up in the fifth place in the voting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Men%27s_Player_of_the_Year_Award#2017%E2%80%9318

Answer (score 1):

Because winning the Champions League is like having a multiplier. In fact if you notice, almost always, the player that wins UEFA Player of the Year have won Champions League that year.

I made a table with the winner, the year, and the team who won the Champions League and you will see what I mean:

- Modric 2018 (Real Madrid)
- Ronaldo 2017 (Real Madrid)
- Ronaldo 2016 (Real Madrid)
- Messi 2015 (Barcelona)
- Ronaldo 2014 (Real Madrid)
- Ribery 2013 (Bayern München)
- Iniesta 2012 (Chelsea)
- Messi 2011 (Barcelona)

You can notice that the only exception is 2012 when Iniesta won the award, but Chelsea won the cup.

This year is no exception. In fact the first three players are Modric and Ronaldo, who won the 2018 Champions League and Momo Salah that had an astonishing season with Liverpool and played in the Champions League final.